# Do I really need a weight in the front of my tractor when farming?

Tags: farming-simulator-2017

When I started this game, I immediately went online (no tutorial) and did some farming tasks (cultivating and planting) with the smaller tractor.  Now I decided to go to the tutorial to get a better understanding of the tasks and the tutorial makes me carry a weight in the front of the tractor to balance out the load.  Is there any downside to not having a weight in the front of the tractor?  I ask as I was able to farm online without the front weight without any issues.

[image]

Comment: Your attachment in that screenshot has wheels, so you have some added ground support there, and that tractor is a decent size. Weight matters more with attachments that are suspended off the ground, like a seed / fertilizer/ water attachment, and even moreso on smaller tractors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, but not all the time.**

It will never be a factor until you put a heavy attachment on, but improper weight distribution can literally lift your tires off the ground. Certain vehicles are heavy enough that this is not a problem, but the smaller tractors, with the larger attachments, will tip backwards or forwards.

I believe I personally ran into this when, in FS15, i put an upgraded fertilizer attachment on the back of the basic, free tractor they give you when you start.

Edit:

I found some [forum posts](https://steamcommunity.com/app/313160/discussions/0/535150948604413965/) that talk about it happening a bit, and there are some mods (linked to in the post) that help with weight issues. However, I found a screenshot of it happening, to a somewhat extreme degree:

[image: gravity farming]

Comment: What happens if the front tires are lifted off the ground? Am I unable to turn then?

Comment: Yep, I believe it eliminates turning if the front is up, and acceleration if the back is up